# Groupby 2 categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | memory confidence | Test (1= correct, 2=incorrect) | Experiment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 1 | Experiment 1 |
| 1 | 78 | 0 | Experiment 1 |
| 1 | 98 | 0 | Experiment 1 |
| 1 | 24 | 1 | Experiment 2 |
| 2 | 45 | 0 | Experiment 2 |
| 2 | 87 | 1 | Experiment 2 |

I want to see if a person's average confidence is correlated with their performance on the test. So I have written the following code, which shows a persons average memory confidence, and their average score:

df3 = df.groupby(['PID'])['accuracy','memory_confidence'].mean()

i = sns.lmplot(x = 'memory_confidence', y = 'accuracy', data = df3)

**What I want to do now is to compute different correlations/ lmplots for Experiment 1 and Experiment 2**

adding in 'source' does not work, as I get **KeyError: "['source'] not in index"**

df3 = df.groupby(['PID',***'source'***])['accuracy','memory_confidence'].mean()

i = sns.lmplot(x = 'memory_confidence', y = 'accuracy', ***hue='source'***, data = df3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 56, 1,  'Experiment 1'],
    [1, 78, 0,  'Experiment 1'],
    [1, 98, 0,  'Experiment 1'],
    [1, 24, 1,  'Experiment 2'],
    [2, 45, 0,  'Experiment 2'],
    [2, 87, 1,  'Experiment 2']
], columns=['ID', 'memory_confidence', 'accuracy', 'Experiment'])

sns.lmplot(x = 'memory_confidence', y = 'accuracy', hue='Experiment', data=df)
plt.show()


exp1 = df[df['Experiment'] == 'Experiment 1']
exp1_corr = exp1.corr().loc['memory_confidence', 'accuracy']
exp2 = df[df['Experiment'] == 'Experiment 2']
exp2_corr = exp2.corr().loc['memory_confidence', 'accuracy']
print(exp1_corr, exp2_corr)
```

Produces the following:

[image]

```
-0.8794395358869003 0.18898223650461368
```